# Subversion usage log analysis

Tags: svn, logging, statistics

We want to start analyzing usage of our various Subversion repositories, which is something I know is stored in our Apache logs. The problem is that I don't know of any tools out there for doing this. If, for example, I want to get a listing per repository of "There were X1 checkins and Y1 checkouts on day W1, X2 checkouts and Y2 checkins on day W2..." is there a tool that will scrape Apache logs and give me those stats? Either my Google-fu seems weak in this area or there's really nothing available.

I'm guessing this is something that most server log analysis tools like AWstats and Webalyzer won't do.

Answer (score 2):

You should try [StatSVN](http://www.statsvn.org/) It's the one I'm using in my company and gives the type of statistics you're looking for.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I looked at StatSVN, and while it is chock full of info, it doesn't actually give the stats I specified above. It will give checkins, yes, but has no way of analyzing checkouts, which is equally important for our purposes.

Comment: Hi Chris,

You're right, there's no way of analyzing checkouts using StatSVN.

Thinking about it, the checkout is requested by the client, and I don't think that any of the svn hooks will help.

Comment: Furthermore, StatSVN requires to checkout a copy of the repo. You need to reserve at least 50% of space for this task only.